# How to save shared folder to users account of Google Drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am working on Google Drive Project and scene is that I want to copy whole shared folder from one account to another by using Google Drive API. I was successfully able to write code of saving shared file in google drive and here is the code.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));

        },

        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1B9a4JSUCET5DQkrp4-eMpcTLx7_YL6fM/copy",
        data: JSON.stringify({


            
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",


        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        },


        timeout: 60000
    });
```

So from refrence to above code please help me to save whole shared folder to drive. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: what part of your code has to do with saving and what are the errors you are getting?  We need to see the code you are using.

Comment: I am not getting any error because this is code of saving a shared file to my account, I am using javascript ajax to save a file but I want to save whole folder instead of file. I just can't understand how should I save the folder by sending ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy?hl=en) method you can't copy folders:

> Creates a copy of a file and applies any requested updates with patch semantics. Folders cannot be copied.

You would have to create the same folder and copy each file from the shared folder to the new one.

You would have to get all the files from that folder with [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and then get the ID and copy them.